# Dynamic field and get_object_or_none

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using this snippet https://gist.github.com/735861 to encrypt the pk of my model.

If I use the normal way of getting a single object `MyModel.object.get(encrypted_pk=url_pk)` it works flawlessly. But if I use the `get_object_or_none` function from [here](https://github.com/ekarulf/django-annoying/blob/master/annoying/functions.py#L5) it throws the following error `FieldError. Cannot resolve keyword 'encrypted_pk' into field.`

I suspect the problem is the way the manager is implemented. Any way to fix it?

Comment: How do you call the get_object_or_none?

Comment: @sergzach `obj = get_object_or_none(MyModel, encrypted_pk=url_pk)`

Comment: Probably you have a typo in one character. Does it output 'Choices are <list_of_possible_fields>'?

Comment: @sergzach I'm pretty sure it's not a typo

Comment: Could you check MyModel._default_manager ?

Comment: @sneawo `<apps.core.pk_encoder.EncryptedPKModelManager object at 0x105433bd0>`seems to be the correct one

Comment: @JuanRiaza Yes, it's correct. I posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be solved in such way:

```
class EncryptedPKQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        encrypted_pk = kwargs.pop('encrypted_pk', None)
        if encrypted_pk:
            # If found, decrypt encrypted_pk argument and set pk argument to the appropriate value
            kwargs['pk'] = struct.unpack('<Q', self.model.encryption_obj.decrypt(
                struct.pack('<Q', base36decode(encrypted_pk))
            ))[0]
        print kwargs
        return super(EncryptedPKQuerySet, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)

class EncryptedPKModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return EncryptedPKQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

Because in `get_object_or_None` QuerySet is builded as `model.manager.all().get(...)` and `all()` returns QuerySet instance.